# pull out lines that contain 1 in 3rd column

Tags: text-processing

I've got a text file with 633K lines all have 3 columns

```
768844  30050038638556  0
768892  30050018569904  1
768967  30050028970902  0
```

How do I pull out in a file those lines that have "1" in the 3rd column, result should be only lines with 1

```
768892  30050018569904  1
```

Comment: my example does not show each in a separate line

Comment: The curly brackets help with that...

Comment: Is column 3 always 1 or 0? I.e. Should column 3 contain 1 or be equal to 1?

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

If you want column 3 to be exactly '1', then:

```
awk '$3==1' input > output
```

If you want column 3 to *contain* '1', then:

```
awk '$3~1' input > output
```

In case you prefer sed, here's one for "column 3 is exactly 1":

```
sed -rn '/^[^ ]*[ ]*[^ ]*[ ]+1$/ p' input > output
```

... and sed for "column 3 contains 1":

```
sed -rn '/^[^ ]*[ ]*[^ ]*[ ]+.*1.*$/ p'
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming there's no whitespace after the third column (i.e. the number is at the very end of the line) and that you're only dealing with single digit numbers on the third column:

```
grep '1$'  input.txt > output.txt
```